# Merge two pandas dataframes but print all possible matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dfs that looks like:

```
NAME        GROUP
Thomas      1
Jan         1
Thomas      2
Marco       2
Antonio     3
Julio       3
Thomas      3
```

```
NAME        STREET
Thomas      Pine
Jan         Park
Thomas      Main
Marco       Fifth
Antonio     Sixth
Julio       Crown
Thomas      King
```

Desired output:

```
NAME        GROUP      STREET
Thomas      1          Pine,Main,King
Jan         1          Park
Thomas      2          Pine,Main,King
Marco       2          Fifth
Antonio     3          Sixth
Julio       3          Crown
Thomas      3          Pine,Main,King
```

So essentially I would want to merge the two dataframes on “NAME” but I would want to have it print all the possible combinations for street.

What I tried is:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on = 'NAME’)
```

But this gives me just:

```
NAME        GROUP      STREET
Thomas      1          Pine
Jan         1          Park
Thomas      2          Pine
Marco       2          Fifth
Antonio     3          Sixth
Julio       3          Crown
Thomas      3          King
```

Is it possible at all to get the output I want using the merge? I have tried reading the documentation but couldn’t get to the right output…

Comment: Aggregate `df2` first and then `merge`: `pd.merge(df1, df2.STREET.groupby(df2.NAME).agg(",".join), left_on='NAME', right_index=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `groupby` before `merge`

```
out = df1.merge(df2.groupby('NAME',as_index=False)[['STREET']].agg(','.join),how='left')
Out[374]: 
      NAME  GROUP          STREET
0   Thomas      1  Pine,Main,King
1      Jan      1            Park
2   Thomas      2  Pine,Main,King
3    Marco      2           Fifth
4  Antonio      3           Sixth
5    Julio      3           Crown
6   Thomas      3  Pine,Main,King
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked! In case I have an additional column in df2 'CITY', is it easy to have this one also printed? I tried: out = df1.merge(df2.groupby('NAME',as_index=False)[['STREET','CITY']].agg(','.join),how='left') , but it didn't work.